# How can I partially read a huge CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big csv file so that I can not read it all into memory. I only want to read and process a few lines in it. So I am seeking a function in Pandas which could handle this task, which basic python can handle well:

```
with open('abc.csv') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    # pass until it reaches a particular line number....
```

However, if I do this in pandas, I always read the first line:

```
datainput1 = pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep=',', header=None, nrows=1)
datainput2 = pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep=',', header=None, nrows=1)
```

I am looking for some easier way to handle this task in pandas. For example, if I want to read rows from 1000 to 2000. How can I do this quickly?

I want to use pandas because I want to read data into the dataframe.

Comment: petezurich answer should be accepted. The definition of `nrows` specifically says it's "Useful for reading pieces of large files."

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use [`chunksize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
for df in pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep=',', header=None, chunksize=1):
    #do something
```

To answer your second part do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep=',', header=None, skiprows=1000, chunksize=1000)
```

This will skip the first 1000 rows and then only read the next 1000 rows giving you rows 1000-2000, unclear if you require the end points to be included or not but you can fiddle the numbers to get what you want.

Answer (score 33):

In addition to EdChums answer I find the `nrows` argument useful which simply defines the number of rows you want to import with [pandas' read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Thereby you don't get an iterator but rather can just import a part of the whole file of size `nrows`. It works with `skiprows` too.

```
df = pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep=',', header=None, skiprows=1000, nrows=1000)
```