# python - Using pandas structures with large csv(iterate and chunksize)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a large csv file, about 600mb with 11 million rows and I want to create statistical data like pivots, histograms, graphs etc. Obviously trying to just to read it normally:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Check400_900.csv', sep='\t')
```

Doesn't work so I found iterate and chunksize in a similar post so I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
```

All good, i can for example `print df.get_chunk(5)`  and search the whole file with just:

```
for chunk in df:
    print chunk
```

My problem is I don't know how to use stuff like these below for the whole df and not for just one chunk.

```
plt.plot()
print df.head()
print df.describe()
print df.dtypes
customer_group3 = df.groupby('UserID')
y3 = customer_group.size()
```

Comment: You haven't posed a question. What is your question?

Comment: @saladi My question is how can i work with the df without having to load it into memory all at once.

Comment: I think the question you were refereing to is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334463/how-can-i-partially-read-a-huge-csv-file

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solution, if need create one big `DataFrame` if need processes all data at once (what is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642951/python-using-pandas-structures-with-large-csviterate-and-chunksize/33646592?noredirect=1#comment87785106_33646592)):

Then use [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for all chunks to df, because type of output of function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
```

isn't dataframe, but `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader` - [source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).

```
tp = pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
print tp
#<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x00000000150E0048>
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

I think is necessary add parameter [ignore index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis) to function `concat`, because avoiding duplicity of indexes.

EDIT:

But if want working with large data like aggregating, much better is use [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv), because it provides advanced parallelism.

Comment: He can just do `tp.read()` to get a dataframe but it probably won't fit into his memory so he asks if you could work without loading it fully.

Comment: I have tried that but i run out of memory again, 'MemoryError'

Comment: The size of my memory is 6gb

Comment: I get error NotImplementedError: 'nrows' and 'chunksize' can not be used together yet. Should i remove chunksize?

Comment: Well (for some reason i dont know) i have 3 Unnamed columns with just a counter, and then i have 4 columns which i need

Comment: Yes my csv file is separated with tab and you can take a look at how my df looks like here [link](http://prntscr.com/91imra)  
p.s. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is a terrible idea, for exactly the reason @hellpanderr suggested in the first comment. This has the same effect as just calling `read_csv` without using `chunksize`, except that it takes twice as much memory (because you now have to hold not only the giant DataFrame, but also all the chunks that add up to that DataFrame at the same time). This cannot possibly solve the OP's problem, it only makes it worse.

Comment: It's _not_ working. He says it works "only for 10000 rows". His actual data is 11 million rows. You apparently managed to convince him, incorrectly, that what he wanted to do was impossible. And that's not going to change two and a half years later. So there's no point in discussing it further.

Answer (score 21):

You do *not* need `concat` here. It's exactly like writing `sum(map(list, grouper(tup, 1000)))` instead of `list(tup)`. The only thing `iterator` and `chunksize=1000` does is to give you a reader object that iterates 1000-row DataFrames instead of reading the whole thing. If you want the whole thing at once, just don't use those parameters.

But if reading the whole file into memory at once is too expensive (e.g., takes so much memory that you get a `MemoryError`, or slow your system to a crawl by throwing it into swap hell), that's exactly what `chunksize` is for.

The problem is that you named the resulting iterator `df`, and then tried to use it as a DataFrame. It's not a DataFrame; it's an iterator that gives you 1000-row DataFrames one by one.

When you say this:

> My problem is I don't know how to use stuff like these below for the whole df and not for just one chunk

The answer is that you *can't*. If you can't load the whole thing into one giant DataFrame, you can't use one giant DataFrame. You have to rewrite your code around chunks.

Instead of this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
print df.dtypes
customer_group3 = df.groupby('UserID')
```

… you have to do things like this:

```
for df in pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000):
    print df.dtypes
    customer_group3 = df.groupby('UserID')
```

Often, what you need to do is aggregate some data—reduce each chunk down to something much smaller with only the parts you need. For example, if you want to sum the entire file by groups, you can `groupby` each chunk, then sum the chunk by groups, and store a series/array/list/dict of running totals for each group.

Of course it's slightly more complicated than just summing a giant series all at once, *but there's no way around that*. (Except to buy more RAM and/or switch to 64 bits.) That's how `iterator` and `chunksize` solve the problem: by allowing you to make this tradeoff when you need to.

Comment: Slow compared to what? Calling `groupby` on a 1000-row chunk takes exactly as much time as calling `groupby` on a 1000-row whole-file DataFrame. Which takes under 1ms on my laptop. If you have to do that 1000 times, it takes almost a second. Is that too slow to process a file that you otherwise couldn't process at all?

Answer (score 6):

You need to concatenate the chucks. For example:

```
df2 = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in df])
```

And then run your commands on `df2`

Comment: Thanks for your response but again i get ''MemoryError''

Comment: This is just a slightly worse version of jezrael's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might not reply directly to the question, but when you have to load a big dataset it is a good practice, to covert the dtypes of your columns while reading the dataset. Also if you know which columns you need, use the `usecols` argument to load only those.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", 
            usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'Date'],
            dtype={'A':'uint32',
                    'B':'uint8',
                    'C':'uint8'
                    },
            parse_dates=['Date'],  # convert to datetime64          
            sep='\t'
           )
```

Comment: If this doesn't answer the question, you can add this information as a comment.

Comment: I must have at least 50 reputation to comment :/. I thought this suggestion would be useful to be here, for anyone working on "big" datasets. (I can comment only to my own answer)