# How to open large fiile (9gb) using python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I need to analysis data, but file is 9Gb. When I try to open it Python is interrupted and return `MemoryError`.

`data = pd.read_csv("path.csv")`
Is there any way to solve this problem or I should drop this file?

Comment: Do you need to open the entire file? you can pass `chunksize` param to `read_csv` which will return a chunk at a time, also are you using 64-bit python, OS etc

Comment: What sort of data does it contain?  Maybe a sample line or two would help.  And do you need all the data inside it, or just a subset?  How much memory do you have on your system?  Have you tried a 1 GB subset of this file?  Do you have a 64-bit OS?  Which OS?

Comment: If you'll use your file as a generator (with open(file) as f: for line in f) then you will not have to upload this at once and will be able to do something iteratively. I don't think you will be able to use pandas though, because it assumes you can fit file in memory

Comment: windows 64. I need all data from this file. I have free 793 GB. And I have 4 columns

Comment: It works to file size 1.5GB

Comment: If you are not restricted to `pandas`, you can use [`sframe`](https://github.com/dato-code/SFrame), which is disk-based and thus giving you the possibility to hold datasets that are too large to fit in your system's memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642951/python-using-pandas-structures-with-large-csviterate-and-chunksize - try using `chunksize` and `concat` as in the answer there.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, i don't think it's a good idea - you'll need more memory for this, compared to reading the whole CSV file into DF in one shot.

Comment: @user6241246, first of all if you can somehow reduce amount of data - you should do it. For example if you don't need __all__ columns for your analysis, you can read only _interesting_ columns using `usecols=['colA','colD']` parameter - this will reduce amount of memory needed for your DF. Beside that if you can do your analysis - chunk-by-chunk, you can use `chunksize` parameter (as it has already been mentioned) and process your data by portions. If nothing else helps you may consider using `Spark SQL` on clustered environment

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by EdChum, I use `chunksize=n` to open big files in chunks, then loop through the chunks to do whatever you need. Specify the number of rows you want in each 'chunk' of data and open as follows:

```
chunks = 100000
data = pd.read_csv("path.csv", chunksize=chunks)
for chunk in data:
    print "something"
```

Hope this helps :)