# How to dump a large csv file to a table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv

I have a `csv` file which is more than `1 GB` in size. Usually this is how I convert a `csv` to a `table` using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

file_path = "/path/to/test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

for col in df.columns:
    # convert each column values to numeric 
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:port/dbname')
df.to_sql("mytable", engine)
```

As you can see, I load up the `csv` file, perform operation on each `column` and dump it to a `table`.

Now since my file is very large, `pandas` is unable to load it in `data frame`. So I looked up a solution online which talked about loading `data` in chunks and performing operations [Using pandas to efficiently read in a large CSV file without crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870220/using-pandas-to-efficiently-read-in-a-large-csv-file-without-crashing). So this is what I came up with

```
file_path = "/path/to/test.csv" 
chunksize = 100000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, low_memory=False):
    columns = chunk.columns
```

It gives me the `columns` of every chunk. So does a chunk size means it reads `n` rows at a time? I can't quite figure out how do I ensure I cover all the chunks and keep appending the `data` to the `table` such that in the end, I have all the `data` dumped to the `table` like I do with smaller `csv` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated docs on `iterator` and `chunksize` can be found here: [Iterating through files chunk by chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).

> So does a chunk size means it reads `n` rows at a time?

Yes.

Your code using `chunksize` is mostly correct, you just need to add each chunk to your dataframe.

If all your columns are the same type and don't require any special logic/types, then convert the entire DataFrame instead of doing it column by column. Or, you can specify `dtypes` to `read_csv`. However, you'd lose access to specify `'coerce'`, so will leave it as is.

For extremely large data, it's better to do the entire read, convert, to_sql in chunks. Also note that it doesn't make sense to use `low_memory=False` in that case, use the default `True`. You're converting the type later anyway, so a mixed type inference (which is what might happen), won't matter.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:port/dbname')
reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=True)
for rows in reader:
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    # column conversions
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
    # sql export
    df.to_sql("mytable", engine)
```

Comment: wouldn't adding chunk to data frame increase memory consumption? Or is it that for each chunk, I need to keep dumping to the database?

Comment: For 1 GB, you could probably hold that in memory and then dump to DB. But you raise a good point, especially for larger sizes. Better to it all in chunks: read, convert, to_sql. But `low_memory=False` doesn't make sense. Have edited my answer with the changes.

Comment: just another question. If I have a csv file which is of very small size, can I still keep the chunk size as same? I am planning to use this code to convert csv of any size to a table.

Comment: Yeah, sure. That works too because if it's very small, it will be processed in a single loop. So apart from _microsecond_ overhead of loop constructs, it will work as well for small files as it does for larger ones.

Comment: Btw, I would recommend that you try to specify `dtypes` in `read_csv` and check if you really need the 'coerce' option. The `for col in df.columns: df[col] = pd.to_numeric...` is the least efficient part of the code, so use it only if it's necessary. If your dtypes are all the same, could also use [`df.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas-dataframe-astype) after `df = pd.DataFrame(rows)`.