# How can you process a CSV from Azure Blob Storage as a stream in Python

Tags: python, azure, csv, stream

It is simple to get a `StorageStreamDownloader` using the azure.storage.blob package:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("my azure connection string")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("my azure container name")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("my azure file name")
storage_stream_downloader = blob_client.download_blob()
```

and it is simple to process a file-like object, or more specifically, I think, a string-returning iterator (or the file path of the object) in the csv package:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
 
csv_string = """col1, col2
a,b
c,d"""
with StringIO(csv_string) as csv_file:
  for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
    print(row) # or rather whatever I actually want to do on a row by row basis, e.g. ascertain that the file contains a row that meets a certain condition
```

What I'm struggling with is getting the streaming data from my `StorageStreamDownloader` into `csv.reader()` in such a way that I can process each line as it arrives rather than waiting for the whole file to download.

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python) strike me as a little underwritten by their standards (the `chunks()` method has no annotation?) but I see there is a `readinto()` method for reading into a stream.  I have tried reading into a `BytesIO` stream but cannot work out how to get the data out into `csv.reader()` without just outputting the buffer to a new file and reading that file.  This all strikes me as a thing that should be doable but I'm probably missing something obvious conceptually, perhaps to do with `itertools` or `asyncio`, or perhaps I'm just using the wrong csv tool for my needs?

Comment: You can use pandas to read CSV file with BytesIO.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks Jim.  I was trying to stick to the specialised csv library as I'm not doing any actual data point analysis but if pandas handles it then I'll give that a go

Answer (score 5):

Based on a comment by Jim Xu:

```py
stream = blob_client.download_blob()  
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
  stream.readinto(buf)

  # needed to reset the buffer, otherwise, panda won't read from the start
  buf.seek(0)

  data = pd.read_csv(buf)
```

or

```py
csv_content = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(csv_content ))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read csv file on row by one row, you can use the method `pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=1)`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870220/using-pandas-to-efficiently-read-in-a-large-csv-file-without-crashing) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

For example (I use pandas1.2.1)

```
with pd.read_csv(content, chunksize=1) as reader:

    for chunk in reader:
        print(chunk)
        print('---------------')
```

[image]

Besides, if you want to use the method `chunks()`, we need to set `max_chunk_get_size` and `max_single_get_size` to the same value when we create `BlobClient`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/15648) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python)

For example

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

key = '<account_key>'

blob_client = BlobClient(account_url='https://andyprivate.blob.core.windows.net',
                         container_name='input',
                         blob_name='cities.csv',
                         credential=key,
                         max_chunk_get_size=1024,
                         max_single_get_size=1024)
stream = blob_client.download_blob()

for chunk in stream.chunks():
    print(len(chunk))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. Will try and get it implemented today and accept answer

Comment: Thanks again for this but I still haven't managed to get this working together.  `content` in your first example seems to be effectively the same as `csv_file` in my question, and I still don't see how I stream azure files into it?  The chunk params in the second example seem very helpful tho, for optimizing once I have the stream processing actually working

Comment: @ChristopherAlcock in the first sample, you can use the method `readinto()` to read into `BytesIO` stream. Then use pandas to process the stream.

Comment: Hi Jim,  I've finally worked out what was going wrong for me here.  The pandas read_csv unsurprisingly returns a pandas dataframe, which behaves very differently to the csv reader, so I had to change all my processing code too, which I hadn't foolishly hadn't expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've worked on this further and whilst if I put my csv data into a BytesIO buffer csv_string like so `buffer = BytesIO(csv_string.encode('utf-8'))`, I can then process it with `pandas.read_csv()`.  However if I get the data from Azure in the way suggested and read that into a buffer, such that calling `.getvalue()` is identical to the buffer from string, pandas cannot process the data: `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError('No columns to parse from file')`.  I am tempted to believe that what I'm trying to do isn't possible

Comment: @ChristopherAlcock please try to use the following code `stream = blob_client.download_blob()

with BytesIO() as buf :
   stream.readinto(buf)
   pandas.read_csv(buf)`

Comment: Hi Jim,  Thanks again for trying, but this is essentially what I was already trying, and despite reading in a very simple valid csv, it returns `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: If I do a `print(buf1.getvalue())` instead of `read_csv`, i get  `b'Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3\nval4,val5,val6\nval7,val8,val9'`, which as far as I can see is totally acceptable csv data