# How to speed up the process of chunk to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use `multiprocessing` to read the csv file faster than using `read_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('review-1m.csv', chunksize=10000)
```

But the `df` I get is not the `dataframe` but of the type `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader`. So I try to use

```
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

to convert `df` into a `dataframe`. But this process takes a lot of time thus the result is not much different from directly using `read_csv`. Does anyone know that how to make the process of converting `df` into `dataframe` faster?

Comment: Just to be thorough, returning the TextFileReader is the [expected behavior](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) when chunking. Using `tp.read()` seems to be a way to read all the data at once as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642951/python-using-pandas-structures-with-large-csviterate-and-chunksize).

Comment: ... if you want to materialize the entire-csv into a data-frame, why do you use `chunksize`...? I don't get what you are trying to do here. What do you mean you "use pool"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, when I say use pool what I mean is using multiprocessing. We use multiprocessing to make the process of reading csv file faster than purely using read_csv.

Comment: @Dan But I already try the code 'df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)' and that costs over 10 seconds for the csv file over 1 million rows.

Comment: Then you want to rethink your algorithm as @juanpa.arrivillaga says. Why read the csv in chunks just to concat again into a DataFrame? That negates the benefits of chunking. Think about your algorithm on the DataFrame and rewrite it to run on each chunk instead. This is similar to what [Blaze](http://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ooc.html) tries to do for out-of-core processing. Process the chunks in memory, store them if necessary, and in the final step you can pull the results together into one DataFrame or file.

Comment: @Dan Thank you! I would reconsider the algorithm in the code.

Answer (score 0):

pd.read_csv() is likely going to give you the same read time as any other method. If you want a real performance increase you should change the format you store your file in.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#performance-considerations

Comment: Thanks! But this is a school project and using csv as the file format is one of the requirements. So I don't think that I could use other formats of my files.

Comment: What sort of operation are you trying to do on the data?

Comment: We apply sql command on those csv files, so we do operations like SELECT and JOIN and WHERE on csv files.