# How to show status before loading a file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple app that uses Pandas and PyQT6 to transform an Excel file into a format that's useful for me.

It works the way I want to, but I'd like to add like a label that'd say "Loading..." whenever the file is loading because read_excel takes a few minutes to do that and I want to indicate that the app isn't stuck, it's just processing.

Whenever I try to do something like below, the label doesn't change at all because the app just gets straight to the read_excel function and freezes until the file is loaded. Does anyone know how to properly do it? Thanks!

```
                self.status_label.setText("Loading...")
                pbireport = pd.read_excel(fname[0])
```

Comment: I think you are referring to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209290/how-do-i-make-a-progress-bar-for-loading-pandas-dataframe-from-a-large-xlsx-file

Comment: @UsamaAleem no, I don't really want a progress bar, just wanna change the label to say "loading". As far as I know you cant make a progress bar when the file is .xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because pd.read_excel(fname[0]) function runs in the main thread. You must use [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html)

Comment: Thank you, now it works the way I wanted & doesn't freeze the entire GUI as well.