# Pandas equivalent of Python's readlines function

Tags: python, pandas

With python's `readlines()` function I can retrieve a list of each line in a file:

```
with open('dat.csv', 'r') as dat:
    lines = dat.readlines()
```

I am working on a problem involving a very large file and this method is producing a memory error. Is there a pandas equivalent to Python's `readlines()` function? The `pd.read_csv()` option `chunksize` seems to append numbers to my lines, which is far from ideal.

Minimal example:

```
In [1]: lines = []

In [2]: for df in pd.read_csv('s.csv', chunksize = 100):
   ...:     lines.append(df)
In [3]: lines
Out[3]: 
[   hello here is a line
 0  here is another line
 1  here is my last line]

In [4]: with open('s.csv', 'r') as dat:
   ...:     lines = dat.readlines()
   ...:     

In [5]: lines
Out[5]: ['hello here is a line\n', 'here is another line\n', 'here is my last line\n']

In [6]: cat s.csv
hello here is a line
here is another line
here is my last line
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv('dat.csv')`?

Comment: read_csv returns a data frame separated by columns, not an array of the lines in the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas read csv file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334463/pandas-read-csv-file-line-by-line)

Comment: you can pass a `chunksize` param, this will return an iterable chunk of the file read into a df

Comment: @munircontractor I included an example showing how these questions are different

Comment: you can append `df.values.tolist()` but why would you do this?

Comment: My file is not a csv file - it doesn't make sense to store it as a dataframe. I am looking for a very specific pattern, line by line.

Comment: So why are you using pandas then, there is no performance gain with what you're intending to do by using pandas

Comment: I am trying to use memory more efficiently in the context of an mpi-related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019498/mpi4py-comm-bcast-causes-memory-error-for-large-objects

Comment: So how does this approach solve this problem? Why does reading a single line at a time improve performance as opposed to reading N lines processing them and then reading a further N lines?

Comment: Doesn't pandas read the csv using precompiled code, decreasing the memory used?

Comment: You're still reading text into some kind of memory structure, you're not intending to use dataframes anyway, just making a list of strings so where does pandas get involved in that step?

Comment: My reasoning was that pandas should be able to capitalize on the mpi communicator and would use memory more intelligently. I do not have proof that this will work, but this strategy seemed like it could work. However, I am very open to other solutions :)

Comment: Your question as stated mentioned nothing about mpi, nor what you intended to achieve or proof that using pandas to simply produce a list of strings helps in anyway

Comment: @EdChum I think I see what you're saying. If I use the `chunksize` parameter will my memory be used more efficiently?

Comment: it will read N lines into a df, you can then process that df, the additional numbers you see are the index values, you can ignore these if required using `df.values.tolist()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should try to use the `chunksize` option of `pd.read_csv()`, as mentioned in some of the comments.

This will force `pd.read_csv()` to read in a defined amount of lines at a time, instead of trying to read the entire file in one go. It would look like this:

```
>> df = pd.read_csv(filepath, chunksize=1, header=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

In the above example the file will be read line by line.

Now, in fact, according to the documentation of [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), it is not a `pandas.DataFrame` object that is being returned here, but a `TextFileReader` object instead.

> - chunksize : int, default None
>
> Return TextFileReader object for iteration. See IO Tools docs for more information on iterator and chunksize.

Therefore, in order to complete the exercise, you would need to put this in a loop like this:

```
In [385]: cat data_sample.tsv
This is a new line
This is another line of text
And this is the last line of text in this file

In [386]: lines = []

In [387]: for line in pd.read_csv('./data_sample.tsv', encoding='utf-8', header=None, chunksize=1):
    lines.append(line.iloc[0,0])
   .....:     

In [388]: print(lines)
['This is a new line', 'This is another line of text', 'And this is the last line of text in this file']
```

I hope this helps!