# How to access or read a particular entry from csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a csv file in python using the following piece of code:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   for row in reader:
      print(row)
```

This reads the complete csv file, but how can I read a particular entry from the csv file?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by particular entry?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334463/how-can-i-partially-read-a-huge-csv-file/44958125

Comment: @SauravPanda for example, my csv file has a table of some data, and  the table has 3 rows and 3 columns. Now I want to read the value stored in the last row and last column (last entry of the table).  How can I read the value stored at this particular index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Assuming your csv uses a delimiter like ",".

Lets say your CSV looks like this:

```
Name, age, gender
A,10,M
B,20,F
C,30,M
```

I would give you a very basic solution for this. this is to get the last row only.

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    data_txt = csvfile.read().splitlines()
    print(data_txt[-1])
```

Suppose you want the gender of last line, then use:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    data_txt = csvfile.read().splitlines()
    last_row = data_txt[-1].split()
    gender = last_row[-1]
    print(gender)
```

You can do this for any element of the file as far as you know the position of data. For last item use -1 as slicing index.

Hope this helps